# Are `\bigl` and `\bigr` supported in MathJax on the Computer Science Stack Exchange?

Tags: support, mathjax, markdown

I was hoping to use [**MathJax**](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on the computer science stack exchange, but, it renders code inside of a bounding box, which usually means an error occurred.

```latex
$ \bigl{ “\mathtt{ALLEE}”, “\mathtt{ALY}”, “\mathtt{ALLY}” \bigr} $
```

$ \bigl{ “\mathtt{ALLEE}”, “\mathtt{ALY}”, “\mathtt{ALLY}” \bigr} $

Are we allowed to make a big left curly-brace by writing `\bigl{`?

What is the error in the MathJax code here?

Answer (score 3):

The characters `{` and `}` are not allowed as delimiters for `\bigl, \left` and such, as these characters have a special meaning within TeX and Mathjax. Instead, the `\{` and `\}` need to be used as delimiter: $\bigl\{ “\mathtt{ALLEE}”, “\mathtt{ALY}”, “\mathtt{ALLY}” \bigr\}$

Answer (score 0):

You can use `\left\lbrace` and `\right\rbrace` to achive what your want.

For example `\left\lbrace \frac{“\mathtt{ALLEE}”}{2} \right\rbrace` would produce $\left\lbrace \frac{“\mathtt{ALLEE}”}{2} \right\rbrace$.

Same can be achived with `\bigl\{ \frac{“\mathtt{ALLEE}”}{2} \bigr\}`, as pointed out [here](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2865/101305).